# Swift UIView.animateWithDuration not animating

Tags: swift, uiview

Im struggling with this piece of code:
It doesn't return an error but simply doesn't animate the color transition.
The color just changes immediately.
Completion returns TRUE.
The similar examples I found unfortunately didn't help :(

Happy to get your input on this, thanks in advance!

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0.0,
        options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut,
        animations:{
            self.pbDayLight.trackTintColor = self.pbBackGroundCol
        }, completion: {(done: Bool) -> Void in
           println("animated \(done)")
})
```

Comment: and changing the color of the layer works?

Answer (score 0):

first make the color something else before changing it. Like so...

```
func changeColor(){
self.pdDayLight.trackTintColor = self.firstcolor

UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0.0,
        options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut,
        animations:{
            self.pbDayLight.trackTintColor = self.secondcolor
        }, completion: {(done: Bool) -> Void in
           println("animated \(done)")
})
}
```

Comment: Aparently, it refuses to animate UIColor. When I change self.pbDayLight.alpha instead, it works. So how can we get the color transition working?